# android native video playback with alpha channel

Tags: android, video, h.264, alpha-transparency

Does android support alpha channel in any of its native supported video formats,  or does anybody has an idea if it is in the pipeline?

Might be possible in h.264  in android in 3.0 ?

Comment: Do you have H.264 video with alpha channel?

Comment: There is no support of alpha channel in native android video playback.
If you wish to play video with alpha compositing it is possible to use some external libraries based on OpenGL.<br><br>
For example, Alpha Movie Library:<br>
https://github.com/pavelsemak/alpha-movie

Answer (score 2):

There is no alpha channel in any video codec - It's just not designed to do that and would vastly increase the size of the file (every pixel in every frame would need transparency data stored in some way)

You could place a transparent view above the video, maybe even make the ENTIRE video partial transparent (on some devices)... but you can't make ONLY PART of the video transparent.  It would be all or nothing.